# Minio presigned url not working in browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, minio

I am generating minio presigned url using code and then trying to open the url in browser but when i am opening that url in browser it gives me below error:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<Key>PAEHXVONAHDVJ/A</Key>
<BucketName>test</BucketName>
<Resource>/test/PAEHXVONAHDVJ/A</Resource>
<RequestId>173708A8FD5721F0</RequestId>
<HostId>fcc0c2f9-167f-4502-981c-61a3fedb3487</HostId>
</Error>
```

Below is the code i am using to create pre signed url :

```
Map<String, String> reqParams = new HashMap<>();
        reqParams.put("response-content-type", "application/json");
        String minioUploadUrl = "";

        try {
            minioUploadUrl = minioPrimaryClient.getPresignedObjectUrl(
                    GetPresignedObjectUrlArgs.builder()
                            .method(Method.GET)
                            .bucket(org) //org is variable here 
                            .object(tId + "/" + task) //task is variable
                            .expiry(60 * 60)
                            .extraQueryParams(reqParams)
                            .build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return minioUploadUrl;
```

Basically i am creating url which will have two folders inside the mentioned bucket and i would like ti upload multiple files inside that.

Same url which is getting generated when i am using through postman it's working fine but in minio server it gets uploaded without name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to generate a presigned url and use it to upload multiple files to a folder? You may need to use `getPresignedPostForm` api. For example:

```java
  PostPolicy policy = new PostPolicy("myBucket",ZonedDateTime.now().plusHours(1));
        policy.addContentLengthRangeCondition(0,100*1024*1024); // file size range
        policy.addStartsWithCondition("key","myDir/); //directory
        return minioClient.getPresignedPostFormData(policy);
```

Then you will get a formData, you can use this formData to upload any file to `myDir/` in `myBucket`.
for example:
[post formData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKZe4.png)

`key` is the objectKey you want upload file to.
`file` is the file you want upload.
You can use this formData multiple times to upload multiple files.